# Can't seem to install any NPM package

Tags: node.js

Node version: `v5.9.0`

NPM: `3.7.3`

Running: `Debian 8`

```
root@mwb:/var/server# npm install mineflayer
/var/server
`-- mineflayer@1.7.3

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/server/package.json'
npm WARN server No description
npm WARN server No repository field.
npm WARN server No README data
npm WARN server No license field.
```

I looked for existing answers but nothing seems to help the issue. Any ideas on what is happening? This happens with every single module I try to install through NPM. Do I need to revert to an older version?

**Edit: It seems running

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -`

instead of

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -`

makes everything run smoothly. Why can't I use node 5??

Comment: It's a warning, not an error, the module is installed, check the `node_modules` folder.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you not use package.json?
npm install mineflayer